# Testing Controller create action with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec2

How do you test a controller create action with a belongs_to association that is required?
If I remove `validates :address, presence: true` it works, but this validation is necessary.

models/accreditor.rb

```
class Accreditor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address, dependent: :destroy
  validates :address, presence: true
```

spec/controllers/accreditors_controller_spec.rb

```
describe AccreditorsController do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'saves the new accreditor in the database' do
      address = FactoryGirl.create(:address)
      accreditor = FactoryGirl.build(:accreditor, address: address)
      expect{
        post :create, accreditor: accreditor.attributes
      }.to change(Accreditor, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
```

Also, the accreditor and address factories work for all other controller actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the best solution.

```
describe 'POST #create' do
  it 'saves the new accreditor in the database' do
    expect{
      post :create, accreditor: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:accreditor,
          address_attributes: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:address))
    }.to change(Accreditor, :count).by(1)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make this change:

```
accreditor = FactoryGirl.build(:accreditor, address_id: address.id)
```

It should work.

But you shouldn't be using a factory here, you should have placed the parameters directly there, since that's how someone posting a form would do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work. It creates the same attributes hash as `FactoryGirl.build(:accreditor, address: address)`